# How to Declate a global Variable in Angular whose value can change?

Tags: angular, typescript

so I want to create a global variable called "SeqNr" initially set to 0 and whose value can be changed from a component, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Declare the variable in a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: can u show me an example code? I'm in a hurry and I would appreciate a precise answer

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable in a service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SharedService {

  SeqNr:number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  setValue(value:number){
   this.SeqNr = value;
  }

  getValue(){
   return this.SeqNr;
  }
}
```

Inject the service to a component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.setValue(5)
    console.log(this.sharedService.getValue())
  }

}
```

Comment: its better make it public, as below example.

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) { }